# Remote command has different umask

Tags: ssh, bash, unix, file-permissions, umask

`ssh user@host "umask"` gives 0174

`ssh user@host` and the umask from server shell gives 0002

Could you please explain how can it happen?

UPD:
Actually, it was /etc/passwd overriding umask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bash man page:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.
> (...)
> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from `/etc/profile` and  `~/.profile`, in that order.

In your first command (`ssh user@host "umask"`) it is not a login shell, in the second case, it is. So check your `~/.bashrc` file for a `umask 0002` command.